# Pydantic optinal throws `Field required` in nested json list

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I have a nested json that I validate with pydantic:

```
app_dict={'apps': [{'app_id': 'a_1',
   'group_id': '123',
   'report_id': '456',
   'principal_id': 'p_1'},
  {'app_id': 'a_2',
   'group_id': '789',
   'report_id': '987'}]}}


class PbiApps(BaseModel):
    app_id: ty.Required[pty.StrictStr]
    group_id: ty.Required[pty.StrictStr]
    report_id: ty.Required[pty.StrictStr]
    principal_id: ty.Optional[pty.StrictStr]
 
class PbiMain(BaseModel):
    apps: ty.Optional[ty.List[PbiApps]]
```

But if I try to parse it into `PbiMain` it throws an ValidationError for `a_2`

```
PbiRoot(**app_dict)


ValidationError: 1 validation error for Settings
apps.1.principal_id
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'app_id': 'a_2', '...test', 'report_id': '789'}, input_type=DictConfig]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
```

I can set the `principal_id: ty.Optional[pty.StrictStr] = None` to make it work but I would rather have the filed not present than of type None.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking the field as `Optional[T]` does not mean the field is *optional* - it merely allows the value to be of type `T` or `None`. If you want to make a field optional (not required), define a default value.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr


class PbiApps(BaseModel):
    app_id: StrictStr
    group_id: StrictStr
    report_id: StrictStr
    principal_id: StrictStr | None = None
```

See https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields

---

If you need to somehow distinguish between an unset and a default value, consider using `model_dump(exclude_unset=True)`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr


app_dict = {
    "apps": [
        {
            "app_id": "a_1",
            "group_id": "123",
            "report_id": "456",
            "principal_id": "p_1",
        },
        {
            "app_id": "a_2",
            "group_id": "789",
            "report_id": "987",
        },
    ]
}


class PbiApps(BaseModel):
    app_id: StrictStr
    group_id: StrictStr
    report_id: StrictStr
    principal_id: StrictStr | None = None


class PbiMain(BaseModel):
    apps: list[PbiApps] | None


assert PbiMain(**app_dict).model_dump(exclude_unset=True) == app_dict
```

---

By the way, consider using `T | None` instead of `Optional[T]` to avoid confusion. See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#using-union-or-optional

Comment: `exclude_unset=True` is the way to go, thanks! I was confused by the typing hints but it makes total sense.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to avoid having the principal_id field in the model when it's not present in the input, you can use pre method in Pydantic. This allows you to preprocess the data before validation.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator
from typing import List, Optional

app_dict = {
    'apps': [
        {'app_id': 'a_1', 'group_id': '123', 'report_id': '456', 'principal_id': 'p_1'},
        {'app_id': 'a_2', 'group_id': '789', 'report_id': '987'}
    ]
}


class PbiApps(BaseModel):
    app_id: str
    group_id: str
    report_id: str
    principal_id: Optional[str]

@validator("principal_id", pre=True, always=True)
def remove_missing(cls, v):
    return v

class PbiMain(BaseModel):
    apps: Optional[List[PbiApps]]

try:
    result = PbiMain(**app_dict)
    print(result)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

The remove_missing validator is used before the actual validation in this example. If the principal_id field is not present in the input, this validator eliminates it, thus removing it from the validation process. It is possible for the Optional type annotation to be present or omitted in the input.

Comment: How should this work? It does not do anything with the key

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?